# Smart filtering of unanswered questions I might be able to answer

Tags: feature-request

Every time I ask a question and go and look for an unanswered question I can have a go at - and rarely find anything in my skillset.  How about if the system was able to make a stab at what you could answer based on previous answers tags, up ticked answers tags etc.

Answer (score 4):

It does -- try visiting the unanswered questions page by clicking the box that says [Unanswered] at the top of the page.

This page uses two sources:

- top 5 tags in questions and answers you've participated in
- your "favorite" tags, if you have them

Note that we define "answered" a certain way:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: How about making that "my tags" tab sortable, especially by most recent first?  Adding "&sort=newest" to the URL doesn't work.  Or enabling hiding of questions that I've read and can't answer.  This tab is only mildly useful to me right now.

Comment: @michael it's sorted by votes then date -- we want the highest *voted* unanswered questions to get answered first. Logic being, more votes, more demand for an answer.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a view that shows me unanswered questions that I can answer.  If you sort by date first, that shows me questions I likely haven't read yet and might be able to answer.  If you sort by votes first, that shows me questions that I likely have read and can't answer.  That view isn't "unanswered questions I can answer", its "unanswered questions in my favorite tags where I can't hide previously read questions I don't want to see over and over again".  That's how I interpret the intent of the original question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the "Interesting Tags" section on the right-hand side of the question list pages is for. Questions which are on tags in your interesting tags section are highlighted in question lists so you can see them quickly.

Comment: you know that "Unanswered" feeds off this same list, right?

Comment: @Jeff - no I didn't- cool! Is that new? Maybe I just missed it.